# Importing many times to succeed

Tags: import

I am trying to import a file of a few KB. I have to import the XML many times in order for WordPress to succeed. Why does this happen? Why does WordPress not import at once?

Comment: Please describe what happens. Do you get error messages? Something else?

Comment: no error messages. When the xml has many terms It simply arrive to step 2, but without any massages of any kind. You have to go back with the browser and then submit again. again and again until wordpress tell you that the process of import is ended.